# kernel warning in logs: set_rtc_mmss can't update from 0 to 58

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I've been seeing a bunch of these log messages

```
Jan 3 00: 58: 57 foo kernel: set_rtc_mmss: can't update from 0 to 58
```

They occur on CentOS 6.4 VMs running on VMware.  I understand it's something to do with the hardware clock not being set properly on the guest OS.  I found this command which sets the hardware clock to the current system time:

```
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

Is this the correct setting for a virtual machine?  Also, where can this be set so it's persistent?  In the kernel boot parameters?  I'd like for newly provisioned VMs to not have this problem.

**UPDATE 1**

As requested:

```
me@foo:~> ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l   43   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.000
+dtc-nist01.ntp. .ACTS.           1 u  174 1024  377    3.311   -8.554   0.497
*nist1-nj.ustimi .ACTS.           1 u  205 1024  377    6.737    3.775   0.433
+nist1-pa.ustimi .ACTS.           1 u   55 1024  377    8.610    4.688   0.337
```

I see vmwaretools is out of date on this VM.  Perhaps the puppet module I have for managing the vmwaretools install did not install it properly.  I'll take a look and get back to you.

**UPDATE 2**

Yes, vmware tools is installed and at the latest version.

```
me@foo:~> ps aux | grep vmtools
root     56021  0.0  0.1  59508  4156 ?        S    Jan09   3:29 /usr/sbin/vmtoolsd
```

**UPDATE 3**

I tried enabling the "Synchronize guest time with host" on the VM:

```
me@foo:~> vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync status
Disabled
me@foo:~> vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync enable
me@foo:~> vmware-toolbox-cmd timesync status
Enabled
```

but I'm still getting those messages.  In fact, `date` and `hwclock --show` are several minutes apart now, whereas they used to be pretty tight.

In the past, older SLES 9 VMs benefited from settings in the VMware article [Timekeeping best practices for Linux guests](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427), but it states that CentOS/RHEL 6 guests do not need any additional kernel parameters set.

**UPDATE 4**

Upgrading to CentOS 6.5 did not help.  The kernel is:

```
Linux foo 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 13:06:13 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is the output of `ntpq -p`? Also did you install VMware Tools?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the reply - I added some some info above.

Comment: To rule out some possibilities? AMD CPUs? ESX or Workstation? If WS, what host OS? CentOS 6.4 VM is it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 64-bit CentOS 6.4 and 6.5.  The VMware host is ESXi, 5.5.0, 1474528.  HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 (Intel Xeon).  Added some updates to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on everything else I've read, it sounds as if these warnings are benign, especially if the `date` on your servers is fine.  A little annoying though.

I'll let this tidbit from ntp.org put me at ease:

Per http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-trbl-spec.htm#Q-LINUX-SET-RTC-MMSS:

> 8.3.4.1.1. What does set_rtc_mmss: can't update from 54 to 5 mean?
>
> The function set_rtc_mmss() updates minutes and seconds of the CMOS
>   clock from system time. It does not update the hour or date to avoid
>   problems with timezones.[1] The message shown was added to make users
>   and implementers aware of the problem that not all time updates will
>   succeed.
>
> Imagine the system time is 17:56:23 while the CMOS clock is already at
>   18:03:45. Updating just minutes and seconds would set the hardware
>   clock to 18:56:23, a wrong value. The solution for this problem is
>   either to wait a few minutes, or to install a kernel patch that fixes
>   the problem. Normally a wrong time in the hardware clock will not show
>   up until after reboot, or maybe after APM slowed down your system.

Answer (score 2):

VMWare does have some suggestions in there knowledge base on how to configure the ntp client in your guest os. First thing is to make sure the vmware-toolbox timesync is disabled, as you only want ntp to update the time.

From [Timekeeping best practices for Linux guests](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427):

This is their sample `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
tinker panic 0
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict default kod nomodify notrap
server 0.vmware.pool.ntp.org
server 1.vmware.pool.ntp.org
server 2.vmware.pool.ntp.org
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
```

The first line (`tinker panic 0`) allows for big time jumps. (e.g. the system state was saved/restored)

An alternative would be to disable ntp in your guest and enable the vmware-tools time syncing.

Comment: I'm trying out `tinker panic 0`, which I did not have.  I'll see how it does in the next day or two.  I actually added this yesterday, but realized the vmware article says to put that setting at the top of `ntp.conf`, so I had to  move it to the top.

Comment: `tinker panic 0` did not help.  After a few days, I'm still seeing the messages.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the latest kernel version for CentOS 6.4? I'd try booting with clocksource=acpi_pm. Also, I'd do ntpdate -u tick.usno.navy.mil && hwclock --systohc and let things sit. If things continue, then add divizor=10 as well.

Honestly, I suspect the problem is partly to do with the code in your particular kernel for setting and reading the real time clock - that's what gets you the error message. The other part is due to virtual time interrupts not being delivered regularily enough or the timer interrupt handler not scaling the kernel time correctly - and this is what gets you the clock drift.

Forcing ntp to be more aggressive is just a crutch for the problem, unfortunately.

Is there a newer kernel available to you? That might be your safest bet. Good Luck.

Comment: CentOS 6.5 was recently released, which we will be rolling out soon.  I will test upgrading one of our test VMs to see if this issue was addressed.

The [VMware article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427) says no special boot parameters for clock are needed for CentOS/RHEL 6 guests.  I will try these out if the OS update doesn't help.

Comment: I know that the article said they aren't needed and I wouldn't presume to second guess it; however, I think it would be very illuminating if changing the clocksource made a difference. While 6.5 may be released, are you saying you are running the most recently patched centos 6.4 kernel?

Comment: I agree, despite the recommendations in the article, its definitely worth a shot.  No I am NOT running the most recently patched kernel.  Our patch rollout process is something we are currently tightening up, so needless to say, we are slightly behind.  Anyway, I'll try updating to the latest 6.4 kernel on one test VM and also try upgrading to the latest 6.5 on another and see if they stop complaining.

Comment: since the bounty is ending soon and I need time to see if upgrading the OS helps (logs look clean so far), I'll award it to you @etherfish.  Wish I could extend the bounty time.  I'll mark the answer as accepted if/when I completely resolve this.

Comment: I'm curious to know the answer too; I won't disappear. Thank you for the bounty!

Comment: I wrote it off as benign.  I'm not going to spend any more time trying to stop the messages from appearing and risk breaking my systems :).

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot to bios
2. Check the system date and time (correct to current's if needed)
3. Esc(exit and approve the changes)

That should work